# Ionic 2 "iPhone-6" is not a valid target for emulator

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

I'm getting an error: `"iPhone-6" is not a valid target for emulator"` 
when I use the following commands:

```
ionic emulate ios --target="iPhone-6"
```

But when I use the following command it works :

```
cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-6"
```

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Run `cordova emulate ios --list` in the terminal to get the accurate names of the optional targets.
It might not recognize `iPhone-6` only, since Apple recently released the iOs 10+ targets, which now available in your XCode alongside the older version, and because of that, you must also add the iOS version.

For instance, it could look something like that:

```
cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-6, 9.3"
```

Assuming you have an iPhone-6 with iOS 9.3 emulator on your system.